# How can I made my code to work for all screen sizes?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter dart ..
When I install the APK in different screens it's looking ugly in some screens the texts and the buttons it's not fitting perfectly to all the screens .

How can I overcome this problem in flutter..

[image]

Comment: Design your layout carefully. Then view it in all resolutions to check if it doesn't get corrupted in some corner case. If you need help with that you should include layout xml here.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter gives you the tools to accomplish what you want. It gives you MediaQuery object, that you cant get the screen height and width in pixels and use it to display the widgets using this info, it also gives you great widgets  as Expanded, Flexible, etc.

The HOW to do this is a wider question and it takes a bit of experience

Comment: Can I get the syntax of the mediaquery?

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context)

That comand will provide you the desired object